# Why the following Javascript code snippet behaving like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = ["d","b","c"]
var a1 = arr
arr.sort()
arr = ["a","b","w"]

console.log(a1) //printing [ 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

In the above snippet the .sort() operation is getting reflected while printing a1. But while I am reassigning arr, why a1 is not referring that new value while printing?

Comment: You reassigned arr, not a1. It looks pretty obvious to me. Variables in JS do not act like pointers.

Comment: with basic research you could have found the answer to this.

Comment: this is the basic of programming: value and reference.
`a1 = arr` mean that you assign reference of arr as value for variable a1. So everything happen with a1 will effect on arr because they point to same value. ( array [d,b,c]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var arr = ["d","b","c"]
> ```

- Creates an array
- Sets the value of `arr` to a reference to that array

> ```
> var a1 = arr
> ```

- Copies the value of `arr` to `a1`, now both variables hold a reference to that array

> ```
> arr.sort()
> ```

- Sorts the array

> ```
> arr = ["a","b","w"]
> ```

- Creates a *second* array
- Sets the value of `arr` to a reference to that array
- `a1` is unmodified, its value is still a reference to the first array

Comment: But, while I am sorting, that is also a mutable operation and it is only modifying `arr` not `a1` . Then why the assignment will not work in the same way?

Comment: @SaikatBhattacharya — "it is only modifying arr not a1" — Wrong. It is modifying the array that both those variables hold a reference to.

Comment: @SaikatBhattacharya — "why the assignment will not work in the same way" — Because assignment overwrites the value of the variable. It replaces the reference with a new value (a difference reference).

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. It really cleared my doubt! :)